# Attendance app with fingerprint authentication

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to create a employee attendance app having finger print sensing.
I want to register each employee finger prints in local database and when employee logins with fingerprint it should be verified with value in database.Can anyone please help me?
Is it possible to register multiple users using fingerprint sensors in marshmallow phones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Nexus FAQs](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6300638?hl=en)

> Your fingerprint data is stored securely and never leaves your Pixel
>   or Nexus phone. Your fingerprint data isn't shared with Google or any
>   apps on your device. Apps are notified only whether your fingerprint
>   was verified.

FingeprintManager only has these 3 features:

`authenticate()` : for authenticating user

`hasEnrolledFingerprints()` : Determine if there is at least one fingerprint enrolled.

`isHardwareDetected()` : Determine if fingerprint hardware is present and functional.

There is no feature to get fingerprint id from the sensor.So your idea of storing fingerprints in database won't work.

Comment: But our phones are authenticating atleast 5 fingers.if That is not possible how can we do this using concept using android phone?

Comment: @anju.johnson As soon as you enroll a finger it is stored securely in your phone itself. As Nexus FAQ suggests it never leaves your phone. The only thing FingerPrintManager returns is that whether the fingerprints with which you are touching the sensor is enrolled in fingerprint db of phone or not. If fingerprint is enrolled it authenticates otherwise it won't. It works like any app lock available in marketplace.

Comment: We are trying to make a separate android application for this purpose.

Comment: @anju.johnson but to make any application using Fingerprint sensor you have to use FingerprintManager Class and FingerprintManager class only supports the above mentioned methods. Which again makes it impossible to generate any kind of unique id from fingerprint sensor to store it to your local database.

Comment: @anju.johnson An android device with fingerprint sensor cannot act like a bio-metric device used for attendance system.

Comment: So are you trying to say that the only way to implement this is by an external finger sensor device?

Comment: @anju.johnson For now yes you need some other hardware device to achieve your goal. Just like vendors use for UPI transaction through aadhar card fingerprints

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @anju.johnson My pleasure. Please accept the answer if you feel it helped you in clearing the doubts about android fingerprint sensor.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can only use the stored fingerprints to check the authenticity of the user, but you cannot store the unique fingerprints while capturing them through the fingerprint sensor.

This is a big limitation of Android's fingerprint sensor, and hopefully/maybe the future updates of Android will take into account of the usability of the fingerprint sensor to get unique fingerprints to store(as you wanted).

This limitation is present currently in Android's ecosystem to prevent security risks involved with the fingerprint sensor, if used by some malicious app. Through this, it can get the bio-metric details of the user, which may attract huge privacy issues and other security issues about the android's security ecosystem.

Hope it helps and explains the limitation well.